# What is the best way to manage iOS UDID's for client ad hoc distributions?

Tags: ios, adhoc, udid

Given the 100 device limitation per year, what is the best way for a developer to develop applications for clients without exceeding their own personal developer account's limitation?

Should developers require their clients to join the iOS developer program and then add devices to the client's account instead?

Comment: You should consider to accept answers or people won't answer to your questions in the future... ;)

Comment: Is there a time limit by which I must accept an answer? It has only been 2 days and I only got one answer, dude.

Comment: I was not talking about this particular question, but your low accept ratio in general, that has raised a bit since I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I try to only choose answers I feel are satisfactory.  I don't want to choose answer just to boost my profile.  Some of my questions don't have any answers at all!

Comment: So @gonzobrains, what did you do in the end?

Answer (score 1):

I require all my clients to join the developer program since I consider they should be publisher of their apps, which is, imho, ***important from a legal point of view***.

Most of them want anyway to see the name of their company in AppStore.

If 100 devices is really not enough for you, maybe Apple enterprise plan might help.

Comment: How many IDs you get for the enterprise plan?  Yes, I understand the client should publish them app themselves but many clients I get are doing in-house, proof-of-concept, or other apps that they don't want published in the app store.

Comment: Then from what you say, your client needs the enterprise plan, ad-hoc != in-house. From memory I heard 5000, but It might be more, probably unlimited since you do not require to get udids anymore but just deploy a certificate. Look at this > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916827/how-distribute-private-program-to-more-than-100-devices and this > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007954/using-ios-developer-enterprise-program-for-beta-testing

Comment: I don't have any one particular client that needs 5000.  I have many small ones who are just starting out.  I just don't want to exceed my own 100 device limit.  Perhaps requiring them all to have their own accounts is the best way?