# Best way to distribute my iOS app to testers?

Tags: iphone, ios, iphone-developer-program, in-house-distribution

We are enrolled to the regular iOS developer program and entitled to 100 UDIDS. We use them for testing and special in-house distribution. Soon we will run out of UDIDs so what is the best option for us? Should we join the iOS developer enterprise program? Can we use it for regular app store distribution (as part of the regular iOS developer program) and in-house/testing distribution?

Also, is there an easy way to deliver these private builds without iTunes? OTA perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried [Testflight](https://testflightapp.com/)?
It should definitely be able to help with your beta testing efforts.

Comment: And has great support of Bug tracking with there SDK.

Comment: But I still need extra UDIDS. The benefit of TestFlight is OTA distribution.

Comment: You can also do OTA without TestFlight, if a third party service is too much hassle, you don't need the analytics/bug reporting SDK and you don't mind writing some php: http://www.paradeofrain.com/2010/11/taking-the-pain-out-of-ad-hoc-testing/

Comment: TestFlight is great, but it doesn't help with the running out of UDIDs problem.

Comment: The only way I see to get more than 100 devices is enroll a dummy developer account. You will have to maintain two separate build for each of the 100-device groups, with different app IDs (e.g. com.mycompany.myapp and com.mydummycompany.myapp) so it's very inelegant.

Comment: In any case, I am interested in Why you need more than 100 UDIDs

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question! Some companies/institutions are large and may require more than 100 developer devices/testers.

Answer (score 0):

Use Adhoc Provisioning profile.For more details go through this link

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/ProvisioningPortal_Recipes/CreatingaDistributionProvisioningProfile/CreatingaDistributionProvisioningProfile.html

Comment: This doesn't address their actual question.

Answer (score 0):

IN MY OPINION IT IS NOT RECOMMENDED TO BUY AN ENTERPRISE ACCOUNT JUST AS AN WORK AROUND FOR EXTENDING UDID'S. DO YOU ACTUALLY REQUIRE TESTING IN MORE THAN 100 DEVICES?

[Using iOS Developer Enterprise Program for beta testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007954/using-ios-developer-enterprise-program-for-beta-testing)

If you really want to go for enterprise program:

You need to purchase an additional enterprise program. You can use enterprise program for testing in unlimited devices and developer program for posting it into app store. **You cannot post applications into App store using an enterprise account.**

https://developer.apple.com/programs/start/ios/

Comment: You mean I need to purchase the enterprise program *in addition* to the regular program or the enterprise program includes app store distribution? Is there any official document that can clarify this?