# Ad Hoc Test builds for other companies in the iOS Developer Enterprise Program

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios-provisioning

My company is enrolled in Apple's Enterprise Program. We're doing demo/test builds for employees of other companies. [According to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enterprise.html), we can't use the enterprise program for deploying apps to the employees of other companies. But does that include **sending of Ad Hoc test builds to testers at other companies**?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007954/using-ios-developer-enterprise-program-for-beta-testing) addresses a very similar, but not identical, question. We're not wanting to use Enterprise Program to get around any 100 device limit - we're not having issues with that.

It seems to be a bit of a grey area. TestFlight works with builds we send, created with the Enterprise Program, as long as the appropriate UDIDs of tester devices are in the provisioning profile. But isn't that technically still 'illegal' according to Apple, if we're sending the test build to an employee in a different company (even with UDID in the profile)?

<strike>My current take on the situation is that we should be signed up to the regular developer program too, and use the regular program to sign Ad Hoc builds that go to testers at other companies. Correct?</strike>

**Update**

I'm pretty certain Jonathan's answer is correct.

Comment: Why is this voted for closure? It certainly seems to fit "practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face".

Comment: Should it be transferred to Ask Different?

Comment: it isn't a programming issue. on SO's area51 there is a new board just for these kind of issues

Comment: Cheers, didn't know about that. You mean the App Store one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that the Enterprise Program allows for both internal distribution as well as a 100 device Ad-Hoc for testing. I think the crucial thing here is that you don't distribute an application signed for internal use to external "testers" because this will violate the agreement rather make sure you use the ad-hoc method.

Best Jon

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jon. Do you have any links that would back up this idea?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/programs/terms/ios/standard/ios_program_standard_agreement_20120912.pdf     Section 7.2 states you can distribute any group affiliated to you. I think that means pretty much anyone you know.

Comment: So what I'm saying is that the enterprise program includes both the facility to distribute internally as well as whats available in the standard program (the ability to distribute ad-hoc). So in answering your question theres no need to sign up seperately to the regular program just make sure you use the ad-hoc distribution certificate when deploying to external users.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I've updated my question with further comment. Will leave question open a few more days for any more comment, but after that time I'll in all likelihood accept your answer!

Comment: @Bushbert I'm no lawyer (but I DID stay at a Holliday Inn Express - zing!) but to me that line means consultants, contractors i.e. 'affiliates', not just random folks "you know". Wish the Apple language was more clear on this point though